# Unable to find azure.commons.ServicePrincipalCredentials Function in Azure Python SDK

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-python

I am unable to find the function in the Azure Python SDK documentation, but it works in python code as a library

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean azure.common.credentials.ServicePrincipalCredentials?

If it is, the doc is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/msrestazure/msrestazure.azure_active_directory.serviceprincipalcredentials?view=azure-python).

And source code is [here](https://github.com/Azure/msrestazure-for-python/blob/master/msrestazure/azure_active_directory.py#L328) in GitHub.